# How to clear terminal and scroll back in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, console.log, nodemon

I'm using nodemon and want to remove the scroll back whenever it detects a code change.

I tried `console.clear()` but this does not clear history.

What I am trying to do is to send the terminal escape sequence ESC [ 3J - clear screen + history. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command

index.js:

```js
...
var cmd = '3J';
const seq = `\x1B\x5B${cmd}`;
console.dir(seq,{showHidden:true});
debug("Cleared?");
...
```

but the output is:

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
  index:index.js Starts +0ms
'\u001b[3J'
  index:index.js Cleared? +5ms
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you still need an answer for this. I adapted code from user 'jonathan-annett' [here](https://gist.github.com/timneutkens/f2933558b8739bbf09104fb27c5c9664). I basically don't know what the code is doing LOL but after some manipulation I found out a way to make it work...I think.

If anyone can explain what the code inside the process.stdout.write() method is doing, please let me know. I will try to figure it out on my own. But in the meantime, this works for my purposes.

```
function clearConsoleAndScrollBuffer () {
    process.stdout.write('\u001b[3J\u001b[1J');
    console.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found `.clear` can solve it..or open `~/.node_repl_history` can check the history